# Expeceted Declaration when using for loop

Tags: swift, loops

Im just trying to use a for loop to run through some code, but I get an Expected declaration error.

```
   var index = 0

    for( i in 0..< array.count) {

        let commonPrefix = array[i].commonPrefixWithString(array[index], options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch)

        if (countElements(commonPrefix) == 0 ) {

            let string = array[index].uppercased();

            let firstCharacter = string[string.startIndex]

            let title = "\(firstCharacter)"

            let newSection = (index: index, length: i - index, title: title)

            sections.append(newSection)

            index = i

        }

    }
```

Help

Comment: And at what line/column exactly?

Comment: Where is `sections` defined?

Comment: What type is *newSection*?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you write a `for` loop in Swift. What you want is this

```
for i in 0..<array.count {
    // the loop inner body
}
```

Comment: in Swift you should get the array indices property `for i in array.indices`. this way if you are iterating an array slice it won't crash your app